# Don't repeat button in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ng-show` option in AngularJS.

```
<button ng-click="removeFilter();">
<span ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()" ng-show="ctrl.filter[cat]" class="fa fa-close"></span></button>
```

This works very good but if I click second item, this div add another one but one button is enough for me.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just place it **`outside`**

```
<button ng-click="removeFilter();"> </button>
<span ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()" ng-show="ctrl.filter[cat]" class="fa fa-close"></span>
```